# How can you locate a cron job script that's running on a production server?

Tags: scripts, cron

Transitioning development teams and the Cron Job scripts are "unavailable", however, they are still running and being executed.  How can we locate those scripts?

Comment: What do you mean by "unavailable"? Are you saying that you don't have permission to see /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d/? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: The previous developer is stating that he doesn't have access to those scripts, so therefore they are unavailable and we don't have permission to see them.  Is there any way we can retrieve this scripts with this being the case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the table of jobs with `crontab -l`
and edit them if needed with `crontab -e`

A directory which stores a file for each job is often named
`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, and other crontab file locations include (many thanks to *steeldriver* for these) the system-wide crontab file /etc/crontab, as well as possibly the Debian-specific files /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly and any conformant files under /etc/cron.d .

Comment: There's also the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab`, as well as possibly the Debian-specific files `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, `/etc/cron.monthly` and any conformant files under `/etc/cron.d`